# How to make assertions on nested fields with newman

Tags: postman, postman-newman

response

```
{
   user: {
          id: 1000
    }
```

I can make an assertion on the user key

```
pm.expect(response).to.have.key("user")
```

How do I make an assertion that id is there?

I tried this and it doesn't work:

```
pm.expect(response.user).to.have.key("user")
```

Comment: did you try this `pm.expect(response.user).to.have.key("id")`?

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 that results in AssertionError: expected { id: 1294, …(47) } to have key 'id'

Comment: I wonder that your response is json or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
pm.expect(response.user).to.have.property('id')
```